How can I get a DOI for articles from 2008?
I have authored research papers from 2008 in the field of biology, but there are no digital versions available. Is there any way to obtain a DOI for these articles? If so, what steps should I take to register them for a DOI?
The articles were published by my university's periodical, and I am currently unable to contact them because there is a war going on in my country. (I am from Ukraine.) However, I have the titles of the articles. Is it possible to obtain a DOI for them using just the titles, or does it have to be done exclusively through the university?

Why do you want/need a digital object identifier for a non-digital object?

I would like to add them to my ORCID profile. I'll probably need to leave the link so you can verify: https://orcid.org/0009-0003-1772-8284
I hope the moderators won't consider this as spam. There are links to my social media in my ORCID profile, I am a real person.

What is your university's periodical? Can you post a copy on an arxiv server?

It's also not really necessary to identify yourself to get an answer.

You can assign your own DOIs, but you have to go through a service from the DOI Registration Agency.(1) Here is a list of agencies.(2) But there is a charge (this is usually absorbed by your publisher/institution, for example), and it doesn't appear to be cheap, sorry.

Thank you for your response. The second link is exactly what is needed.

I think ResearchGate will provide a DOI for free. Whether you want to support Researchgate is a slightly different question...

You clarified in a comment that you want to assign a DOI to the document in order to add it to your ORCID. In that case, obtaining a DOI should not be necessary. From ORCID's documentation

Add manually
If your work doesn't have a DOI or PMID, you can manually add its information.
For detailed instructions to, see Add works manually.

Basically, scroll down to the "Works" section of your ORCID profile, click the "Add" button and select "Add manually" in the drop-down list.
Should you actually need a DOI then you can have one assigned, as discussed in Eds' answer. But even though DOIs can be assigned to physical objects, DOIs tend to be more useful if they can provide links directly to the document of interest. In case you have the the rights to post the original articles online in some repository (including a reference to the original publication), for example on a preprint archive, that might be a better and cheaper solution. But, of course, you might well have relinquished those rights by transferring the copyright to the publisher.

Thanks for your great response, but I still think Eds' answer is more accurate in addressing my question, as it was specifically about how to get a DOI.

Ethically, you should not create a DOI for something that is not the "version of record". That would normally be done by the publisher.
As others have said, you should not need a DOI to add something to your ORCID record.
